# Отправка ARP запроса через WiFi

Tags: python, python-3.x, сеть

Пытаюсь провести ARP сканирование через WiFi. Получаю список доступных интерфейсов вот так:

```
def GetListOfAvailableNetworkInterfaces():

    Result = None
    c = wmi.WMI()
    qry = "select Name from Win32_NetworkAdapter where NetEnabled = True and 
    NetConnectionStatus = 2"
    Result = [o.Name for o in c.query(qry)]
    return Result
```

Получаю результат:

```
Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165.
```

Проверил через route print - такой интерфейс существует. get_if_list() возвращает то же самое, из чего я делаю вывод, что интерфейс валидный. Отправляю ARP запрос следующим образом:

```
 srp( Ether( dst = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff" ) / ARP( pdst = "192.168.0.0/24" ), timeout = 2, verbose = 0, iface = GetListOfAvailableNetworkInterfaces()[0])
```

Проблема в том, что ответы не приходят, но если сделать все то же самое, но с проводом, то все приходит, вот такой адаптер получаю при подключенном кабеле:

```
Qualcomm Atheros AR8171/8175 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)
```

В указанном диапазоне адресов гарантированно есть хосты. Что я делаю не так в случае беспроводного соединения?

ОС: Windows 10 x64